# How to interpret result when a string of list is passed into the join() function in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, join

I was playing around with join function when I mistakenly passed a list converted to string in the join function. The result is very weird as shown in the code below.

What is the best way to interpret the result?

```
test =  ['2', '1', '3']
s = 'x'
print(s.join(str(test)))
```

Output

```
[x'x2x'x,x x'x1x'x,x x'x3x'x]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically when you type `str(test)` python makes a string `"['2', '1', '3']"`. This is a **string** with 15 characters (don't get confused by the `'`, these are considered characters too.

Now when you do `s.join(str(test))` you can think of it as putting an `x` between each character of the string.

Originally the sequence of characters was:

```py
[ --> ' --> 2 --> ' --> , --> ' --> 1 --> ' --> , -->' --> 3 --> ' --> ]
```

Then `'x'.join(str(test))` placed an `x` everywhere where there is an arrow (`-->`) above.

The typical use of `join` would be to pass a **list** instead of a string as its argument. For example if you wrote:

```py
s.join(test)
```

It would return:

```py
'2x1x3'
```

Answer (score 1):

The .join function combines the elements of a list into a string with some delimiter that you define. If you pass it a string though it will split it into a list to then join it with your delimiter. So you passed it your string list which it split to:

```
'[', "'", '1', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '3', "'", ']'
```

and then it joined with the 'x'

Comment: Thank You. It makes sense now!